# Site Does Not Exist: Flask app on Apache 2.4.29 Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I have looked at all the previous StackOverflow questions regarding this problem but cannot seem to find a solution in any of the answers.

When I run the command:

```
sudo a2ensite WebApp
```

I receive:

```
ERROR: Site WebApp does not exist!
```

This is my file /etc/apache2/sites-available/WebApp:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName 192.168.1.107
        ServerAdmin email@mywebsite.com
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/WebApp/WebApp.wsgi
        <Directory /var/www/WebApp/WebApp/>
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
        Alias /static /var/www/WebApp/WebApp/website/static
        <Directory /var/www/WebApp/WebApp/website/static/>
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I copied that almost verbatim from tech with tim's [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YFBRVJPhDGY).
Except I added the correct file paths and changed

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

to

```
Require all granted
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You should run

`sudo a2ensite CSCI430_CTF1`

instead of

`sudo a2ensite WebApp`

Comment: I wrote the wrong file name, it's WebApp